# How to apply a function to a dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create an app where a user uploads a csv, my user definied function is applied to the data frame and then this new dataframe is displayed. The function does things like changes all text to lower case, removes special character, splits columns, and mutates columns. At the moment the app runs but the dataframe is shown unchanged.

```
library(shiny)

source("prepare-data.R") #my function. It works perfectly outside of 
shiny. 


ui <- fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

  p("Step 1: Upload your csv:"),

  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
    accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated 
    values,text/plain", ".csv"))
    ),

mainPanel(

  p("table will go here"),

  dataTableOutput("processedData")

)
)
)


server <- function(input, output){

data <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return()}
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep =",")
  })

observeEvent(
    input$file1, {
        output$processedData<- renderDataTable({
            prepareData(data())Ta
        })
)

)


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're short a closing curly bracket somewhere.  Also `prepareData(data())Ta` looks wrong.

Comment: Can't leave a comment on stackoverflow yet hence an answer (but it's a comment really, so apologies in advance) Looks like the problem is in the output function - `prepareData(data())Ta` I would check that again. If can you share the code for `prepareData()` that might help provide a better answer.

Comment: What does your function prepareData() look like? I guess it does not return a data frame.